# SQL- Select data from different database's table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, multiple-databases

In SQL Developer, I want to execute a query that selects data from a table in a different database something like :

```
SELECT * 
FROM db2.table;
```

I tried database link &  `GRANT SELECT ON db2.table TO current_Db;` but I still get "table or view does not exist"..
Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you're connected as `current_Db`, what is `db2`, then?

- you said it is a "different database" - I doubt it, somehow. I presume it is actually a "different user in the same database". If that's so, then you should

  - connect as `db2`
  - `grant select on some_table to current_Db`
  - connect as `current_Db`
  - `select * from db2.some_table`
- if it really is a different database, then you should

  - connect as `current_Db`
  - create a database link:

    ```
      create database link dbl_db2 
      connect to db2 
      identified by its_password 
      using <connect string to db2 database>
    ```
  - `select * from some_table@dbl_db2`

---

Based on your comment, it looks that it is the 1st option, after all - two users in the same database. Step-by-step:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> create table test as
  2    select 'Littlefoot' name from dual;

Table created.

SQL> grant select on test to mike;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect mike/lion
Connected.
SQL> select * from scott.test;

NAME
----------
Littlefoot

SQL>
```

Comment: Yes thank you I tried the grant select but I still get "table or view does not exist" when executing ``` select * from db2.some_table ```

Comment: Please, copy/paste every step you made using SQL*Plus. See edited answer, the way I did it.

Comment: I added a comment with a screeshot of sqldeveloper because it is not exactly same database different users

Comment: Unfortunately, a screenshot doesn't help at all. As I said in my previous comment: copy/paste SQL*Plus session which **exactly** shows what you did and how Oracle responded.